# Compare javascript object key with value of input

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have an js object that is stored to variable

```
var data = {
    "France":[
        {
            'population': "8M",
        }
    ],
    "Spain":[
        {
            'population': "18M",
        }
    ]
}
```

and I have an input field that have some value (choosed from dropdown).

```
<input type="text" id="country1" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Select indicator" value="France">
```

I am trying to compare that value of the input with key of the object, and then if that value is equal to the key, to display population number.
So far I tried to do like this

```
$( ".compare button" ).click(function() {
        var c1 = $( ".first-country input" ).val(); //take value from input
        var zemlja = Object.keys(data); //take all keys from object
        var n = zemlja.includes(c1);   //check if value is included in object
        if (n) {
            $(".country1-result h1").html(data.c1[0].population);  //if value is included, add population number to result
        }  
    });
```

And I got undefined. I figure it out that I can not take value if I put variable c1 instead of name of the key. If I put name of the key France, everything works fine, but if I put c1 variable that is equal to France, then it is not working.
Any hint/help how to manage this to work.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice if you can create a runnable snippet of your code. Faster to debug

Comment: You do not need this: `var zemlja = Object.keys(data);`. Instead you can just try `.html(!!data[c1] && data[c1][0].population || '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `c1` is a variable, use bracket notation which will allow you to use property name as variable:

Change

```
$(".country1-result h1").html(data.c1[0].population);
```

To

```
$(".country1-result h1").html(data[c1][0].population);
```

```js
var data = { "France": [{ 'population': "8M", }], "Spain": [{ 'population': "18M", }] }
function myFunction(){}

$(".compare").click(function() {
  var c1 = $(".first-country").val(); //take value from input
  var zemlja = Object.keys(data); //take all keys from object
  var n = zemlja.includes(c1); //check if value is included in object
  if (n) {
    $(".country1-result h1").html(data[c1][0].population); //if value is included, add population number to result
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="country1" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Select indicator" value="France" class="first-country">

<input type="button" class="compare" value="Click" />

<div class="country1-result">
  <h1></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Still not working, I got message Cannot read property of undefined.

Comment: you need to check if `data[c1]` exists. see Artem's answer

Comment: @MarkoPetković, I have updated the answer by adding some HTML and updating few selectors......please check.

Comment: It is working. I checked if data exists. Thanks to all.

Comment: @Mamun I have updated your code and added `myFunction` as it was throwing error. Yes, its a part of OP's code, but users will face this issue so added it. Please revert if the edit is not required.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".compare button" ).click(function() {
        var c1 = $( ".first-country input" ).val(); //take value from input
        var result = data[c1] ? data[c1][0].population : '';
        $(".country1-result h1").html(result);
    });
```